# React: state inside children not updating through props

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

I want to set the state value of children component using props and then display the same for the respective form field. I did that inside the componentDidMount() but it doesn't work.

Code:

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      tweetCount: this.props.tweetCount
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const tweetCount = this.props.tweetCount;
    this.setState({ tweetCount });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <Form>
          <FormGroup>
            <Label for="tweetCount">
              Tweets per Column (between 1 and 30):
              {this.state.tweetCount}
            </Label>
            <Input
              id="tweetCount"
              type="range"
              min="1"
              max="30"
              value={this.state.tweetCount}
              onChange={this.changeTweetCount}
              step="1"
            />
          </FormGroup>
        </Form>
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Component did not mount again. So that lifecycle never fired

Comment: If you are just putting the `tweetCount` into state, you might as well use `this.props.tweetCount` in the render method, and it will always stay up-to-date. If you want to put it in your state, you could use [`componentDidUpdate`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate) and check if the previous `tweetCount` differs from the new `tweetCount`.

Comment: @ShubhamAgarwalBhewanewala okay I will check that

Comment: @Tholle i get Maximum update depth exceeded when i use componentDidUpdate

Comment: @VigneshVeeran It's important to "check if the previous `tweetCount` differs from the new `tweetCount`" as I wrote in my comment, and as the documentation says.

Comment: Use `componentWillReceiveProps` lifecycle hook

Comment: Use conditional updating in component did update using props otherwise it will get into a infi loop

Comment: okay Thank you all :)

Answer (score 1):

If you use React that version is upper than 16.3 then use `getDerivedStateFromProp` so inside of using `componentDidMount` or `componentWillReceiveProps` use this code :

```
static getDerivedStateFromProps(props, state)
{
  return{
    tweetCount:props.tweetCount
  }
}
```